# Need help understanding the argument that "faster than light motion does not imply time travel"

Tags: special-relativity, faster-than-light, time-travel

The paper in question is https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.2528 . But it contradicts known theory. Could someone ELI5? Is it legit? Are there any gotchas or catches?

> **Abstract**
>
> Seeing the many examples in the literature of causality violations
>   based on faster-thanlight (FTL) signals one naturally thinks that FTL
>   motion leads inevitably to the possibility of time travel. We show
>   that this logical inference is invalid by demonstrating a model, based
>   on (3+1)-dimensional Minkowski spacetime, in which FTL motion is
>   permitted (in every direction without any limitation on speed) yet
>   which does not admit time travel. Moreover, the Principle of
>   Relativity is true in this model in the sense that all observers are
>   equivalent. In short, FTL motion does not imply time travel after all.

Comment: What is the first line in the argument that you don't follow?

Comment: What is an ELI5?

Comment: @CinaedSimson “Explain Like I’m 5”

Comment: I don’t know whether it is correct, but it appears “legit”. It doesn’t look anything like what crank physics looks like.

Comment: @WillO Basically the whole thing past the introduction. If you're knowledgeable on the topic can you explain how it's possible for this conclusion to be true while everyone else claims it isn't?

Comment: @pete What known theory are you citing that says FTL motion implies time travel (I am guessing you mean into the past?)

Comment: @aaron Stevens yes, into the past. Theory of relativity proves this, according to most physicists.

Comment: A theory of physics can't prove anything. Only experiments can. I think you mean to say the theory of special relativity predicts this.

Comment: It is not clear what is the logic behind the question. Combining your title and text seems that time travel is implicit in faster than light and this seems to be your assumption rather than known theories.

Comment: @alchimista it follows from relativity according to relativity physicists; the only assumption being made is that relativity is true.

Comment: @aaron Stevens Describe an experiment which proves something is impossible? I don't see how that would work. The best one could do is experimentally verify the theory of relativity, which has already been done.

Comment: I was under the impression that you mean into the past.

Comment: "... Aaron Stevens yes, into the past. Theory of relativity proves this, according to most physicists.". This is the wrong assumption of you, prompted by their introduction as they need a reason to publish in Arxiv. I am not a specialist at all, neither in computer science nor in relativity, but likely this won't have passes any desk in pure physics. Still it might be worth publication, this is not the point.

Comment: @Alchimista Yes, specifically talking about into the past, because time dilation is of course possible all the time. IIUC, FTL leading to causality violation is a well-established fact in Relativity theory ever since Einstein came up with it; it's not an academic paper gimmick. I believe almost all relativity physicists would agree. There are many online resources which illustrate why this is so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bulk of the paper seems fine to me, but at the very end they seem to make an unjustified leap:

> In this paper, we have exhibited a model of Rn1 which is inhabited by observers/particles moving
>   at all (non-light) speeds relative to one another, but in which time travel is not possible – it follows
>   that the existence of FTL signals does not logically entail the existence of ‘time travel’ scenarios.
>   Nor, therefore, does it inevitably lead to the causality paradoxes arising from those scenarios.

All they've proved is that you don't get closed, timelike curves just because you have FTL. (See p. 4 and their definition of "time travel is possible," which is really just a description of a CTC.) This is kind of obvious anyway. But that doesn't mean you don't get causality paradoxes. The tachyonic antitelephone exists any time you have tachyons.

I skipped section 2.2, but people should realize that if you have FTL observers in 3+1 dimensions, then there will not be anything like a Lorentz transformation between STL and FTL observers.